# Linear Search - Python

Tags: python

I'm a newbie and have just started to learn Python. One of my first assignments on my course has asked me to perform a linear search on a list of countries (I know linear search is terrible but it's just for practice sake :) ) and I can't find code for a simple linear search that that doesn't involve integers.

I'm assuming the first step is to create an array, which would be:

```
listCountries = ['France', 'Spain', 'United Kingdom', 'Italy', 'Portugal', 'Ireland', 'Poland', 'Norway']
```

I need to search for "Spain" - what code would I use for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would linear search on integers be that much different than linear search on strings, countries,...?

Comment: Like I said I am very much new to programming, I assumed we used different code dependent on whether the array consisted of integers or characters/wording.

Comment: well Python is a dynamically language, meaning that you can put anything in a list. Therefore in *many* (not all cases), an algorithm that works for a list of integers, will also work for a list of horses, cars, ...

Comment: Aha, okay thank you. I did not know that (I'm basically teaching myself on this CS course). I found code for finding an integer among a list and in the code, I saw it said "int" - which I assumed would only work on integers. I couldn't find the appropriate code for working with chars, words etc. Anywho, that makes things a lot more simpler.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to know if 'Spain' is in the list you can just do:

```
'Spain' in listCountries ## returns true if the string 'Spain' is an element of listCountries
```

there are similar builtin functions to look up its index etc.

If you want to do it manually you (for practice) you could do:

```
def inList (l, elem)
   for e in l:
     if e == elem:
       return True
   return False
```

this will iterate over all list-elements and if it finds the one you are looking for it will return `True`, if what you are looking for is not encountered it returns `False`

If you also care about the index of the element you can do:

```
def whereInList (l,elem): ## return the index of desired element, if not in list return None
  for i,e in enumerate(l):
    if e == elem:
      return i
  return None
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the Linear Search algorithm, I think you have a problem in comparing Strings instead of integers. (If not, use [this](https://pythonschool.net/data-structures-algorithms/linear-search/))

If you want to compare the Strings lexicographically, the Boolean operators in Python do the job for you. In that sense, your code for integers and strings would not be different. Hope this helps you write it, as I don't want to directly give you the code.

You can read [here](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/thinkcspy/Strings/StringComparison.html) for more details.

Comment: I checked out the first link and it was really helpful so thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
countries = ["France", "Spain", "United Kingdom", "Italy", "Portugal", "Ireland", "Poland", "Norway"]

countrie_to_search = 

for index, item in enumerate(countries, 0):
    print("index: {} country: {}".format(index, item))
    if item = countrie_to_search:
        # we have a match, do what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-pythonic but easy to follow approaches.

```
listCountries = ['France', 'Spain', 'United Kingdom', 'Italy', 'Portugal', 'Ireland', 'Poland', 'Norway']

i=0
l = len(listCountries)
while i<l:
  if listCountries[i] == "Spain":
      print "Spain found at index", i
      break;
  else:
      i=i+1
```

Also this one

```
for j in range(len(listCountries)):
    if listCountries[j] == "Spain":
        print "Spain found at index", j
    else:
        continue
```

Sure, you can wrap above snippets inside a function such,

```
def look_for(c, data):
    for j in range(len(data)):
        if data[j] == c:
            return c+" found at index "+str(j)
        else:
          continue
    return c+" not found"

#print look_for("Spain", listCountries) => will return Spain found at index 1
#print look_for("USSR", listCountries) => USSR not found
#print look_for("Finland", listCountries) => Finland not found
```

Below code will do everything for you -))

```
print listCountries.index("Spain")
```

Comment: Amazing - thanks a million. I've got the hang of it now!